# Ruby - I'm having difficulty capitalising specific words in my array which is to be returned as a string

Tags: arrays, ruby, comparison

I've been working on this for a good part of the day and I can get "david copperfield" to return as "David Copperfield", but I'm having trouble getting "the bridge over the river kwai" to return as "The Bridge over the River Kwai".
Here is my code:

```
def titleize(title)
  titleArray = title.split(/ /)
  capitalized = []
  i = 0
  while i < titleArray.length do #I wanted to do some sort of comparison here with an && 
    if i == 0 
      capitalized << titleArray[i].capitalize 
    else 
      capitalized << titleArray[i]
    end
    
    i += 1
  end

  puts titleArray.inspect
  puts capitalized.to_s
end

titleize("david copperfield")
titleize("the bridge over the river kawi")
```

Should I have another array of words to ignore? (`the`, `and`, `but`, `of`...etc) and if so, can someone remind me how to compare the two arrays?

Comment: *"Should I have another array of words to ignore?"* --- Presumably yes, that appears to be the most pragmatic simple solution, given the context you've provided. But really, this is your question to answer, not mine.

Comment: This must be becoming a common interview or homework question,  because there are a now 21 close duplicates for titleizing this particular movie.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal change to your code, to get it working:

```
EXCLUDED_WORDS = ['over', 'the']

def titleize(title)
  titleArray = title.split(/ /)
  capitalized = []
  i = 0

  while i < titleArray.length do
    if i == 0 || !EXCLUDED_WORDS.include?(titleArray[i])
      capitalized << titleArray[i].capitalize 
    else
      capitalized << titleArray[i]
    end
    
    i += 1
  end

  titleArray.join(' ')
end
```

And here is a more ruby-esque version of the same thing:

```
EXCLUDED_WORDS = ['over', 'the']

def titleize(title)
  title.split(/ /).map.with_index do |i, word|
    if i == 0 || !EXCLUDED_WORDS.include?(word)
      word.capitalize 
    else
      word
    end
  end.join(' ')
end
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much for clearing this up.